Copy Folder along with files from Azure Blob to SharePoint
We have a Blob container - Dev. There are multiple sub folders inside
Dev/6c4999ceb9964e0bb08f30790bd9a673/Upload/NativeFiles/
Inside native file there are multiple folders with files.
I have to copy all the folders along with files to Sharepoint that are inside Nativefiles.
Any suggestions to build this using Logic app workflow


Hello @IkhtesamAfrin Could you help to achieve this..

Can you share the workflow diagram which you have tried?

I have added a screenshot of Workflow which i tried. I have created 3 variable
FoldersToProcess - Type - array - value - ["6c4999ceb9964e0bb08f30790bd9a673/Upload/NativeFiles"]
Current folder variable  - to hold current folder value
tempvariable - temporary variable to hold the updated list of folders

Currentfolder - first(variables('FoldersToProcess'))
TempFolder - skip(variables('FoldersToProcess'),1)

@HemantKumar update the details by editing the Qs with more details so that the community can check for possible solutions.

You can use the below workflow to copy folder along with the files from Blob storage to SharePoint.





Code-
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@substring(body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value'][0]?['Path'],0,lastIndexOf(body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value'][0]?['Path'],'/'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Create_new_folder": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "path": "@{outputs('Compose')}"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "sharepointonline"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('*******'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('e2b0ea6'))}/createnewfolder"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Create_file": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@body('Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)')",
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "referenceName": "sharepointonline"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('********'))}/files",
                            "queries": {
                                "folderPath": "@body('Create_new_folder')?['{FullPath}']",
                                "name": "@item()?['DisplayName']",
                                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)": [
                                "SUCCEEDED"
                            ]
                        },
                        "runtimeConfiguration": {
                            "contentTransfer": {
                                "transferMode": "Chunked"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Get_blob_content_using_path_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "referenceName": "azureblob"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/GetFileContentByPath",
                            "queries": {
                                "inferContentType": true,
                                "path": "@items('For_each')?['Path']",
                                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Create_new_folder": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "foreach"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "azureblob"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJ********='))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmZGV2": "/dev",
                    "JTJ********g==": "/dev/6c4999ceb93/Upload/NativeFiles/"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}

Files in Storage Account-

Output-


